# String concatenation. C

Tags: c, string

All of the code below on C.

Both the code snippet below are compiled, but the difference is that the second program crashes at startup.

One:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = "bar";
    char *str[80];;
    strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
    strcat (str, foo);
    strcat (str, bar);
}
```

Two:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = "bar";
    char *str="";
    strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
    strcat (str, foo);
    strcat (str, bar);
}
```

The difference is that in the first case, said the size of the `str` string, while the second is not. How to make string concatenation without a direct indication of the size of the string `str`?

Comment: Is it possible to do string concatenation without a direct indication of the size of the string `str`?

Comment: You have to manage the allocation and deallocation of memory of strings in C. There is no getting around that requirement.

Comment: @user3340536 No, you must specify the size of the array beforehand. If you allocate memory dynamically for the array, then you can resize the array using `realloc` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The difference is that in the first case, said the size of the str
>   string, while the second is not.

No. In the first program, the following statement

```
char *str[80];
```

defines `str` to be an array of `80` pointers to characters. What you need is a character array -

```
char str[80];
```

In the second program,

```
char *str="";
```

defines `str` to be a pointer to the string literal `""`, not an array. Arrays and pointers are different types.

Now, the second program crashes because

```
char *str="";
```

defines `str` to be a pointer to a string literal. The first argument of `strcpy` should be a pointer to a buffer which is large enough for the string to be copied which is pointed to by its second argument.

However, `str` points to the string literal `""` which is allocated in read-only memory. By passing `str` to `strcpy`, it invoked undefined behaviour because `strcpy` tries to modify it which is illegal. Undefined behaviour means the behaviour is unpredictable and anything can happen from program crash to due to segfault (illegal memory access) or your hard drive getting formatted. You should always avoid code which invoked undefined behaviour.

> How to make string concatenation without a direct indication of the
>   size of the string str?

The destination string must be large enough to store the source string else `strcpy` will overrun the buffer pointed to by its first argument and invoke undefined behaviour due to illegal memory access. Again, the destination string must have enough space for the source string to be appended to it else `strcat` will overrun the buffer and again cause undefined behaviour. You should ensure against this by specifying the correct size of the string `str` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

One:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = "bar";
    char str[80];
    strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
    strcat (str, foo);
    strcat (str, bar);
}
```

Two:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = "bar";
    char str[80]="";
    strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
    strcat (str, foo);
    strcat (str, bar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *foo = "foo";
    char *bar = "bar";
    char *str=NULL;
    size_t strSize = strlen(foo)+strlen(bar)+strlen("TEXT ")+1;

    str=malloc(strSize);
    if(NULL==str)
       {
       fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n");
       goto CLEANUP;
       }

    strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
    strcat (str, foo);
    strcat (str, bar);

CLEANUP

    if(str)
       free(str);        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t len1 = strlen(first);
size_t len2 = strlen(second);

char * s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 2);
memcpy(s, first, len1);
s[len1] = ' ';
memcpy(s + len1 + 1, second, len2 + 1); // includes terminating null
```

Did I do good?

Answer (score 1):

In the second version you have set char *str=""; this is equivalent to allocating an empty string on the stack with 1 byte which contains null for end of string. Had you written char*str="0123456789", you would have allocated 11 bytes on the stack the first 10 of which would have been "0123456789" and the 11th byte would have been null. If you try to copy more than allocated bytes to the str, your program might crash. So either allocate dynamically enough memory, or statically.

Answer (score 1):

Both programs are wrong, the first provokes undefined behavior exactly as the second one.
`char *str[80];` is array of pointers which you pass to functions ( `strcpy`, `strcat`) as first argument, while the first argument for those functions should be `char *`. Possible solution for this issue to define `str` as `char str[80];`

The issue with the second program is that `char *str="";` is a pointer to read only piece of memory, which can't be changed.In this case one of possible solutions can be :

```
 char* str = malloc(80);
 strcpy(str,"");
 strcpy (str, "TEXT ");
 strcat (str, foo);
 strcat (str, bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to allocate memory before copying. The first defines the size so as 80 
`char *str =  new char[10];` could also be a method of allocation. `malloc` function could also be used to allocate memory.

Here are some references that might help you

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/